# Excel cell displaying zero instead of a calculated / referenced value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, apache-poi, cell, formula

I am exporting an Excel file with Apache POI using an Excel file as source and for some cells (not all) simply referencing others (like `='worksheet2'.B13`) or calculating a value with referenced cells (like `='worksheet2'.C13 + 'worksheet2'.D13`), they only display zero (0) instead of the right value.

Weird thing is that when I click on the formula and change something in it, as typing a space and deleting it and then I type enter, the right value is displayed !

For info, the type of those cells is "Number / Standard".

I also read somewhere that I should check "Enable iterative calculation" in "Excel options", but it didn't work for me.

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: @Buddha I don't think it's something related to code because it's the same classes that I use to generate the whole file (mainly adding rows and copying formulas) and it is working perfectly for other cells. So I think it's rather something off with the cells.

Comment: Did you try `wb.setForceFormulaRecalculation(true);`? - see this link: http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/eval.html

Comment: Did you ask Apache POI to calculate the cached values of the excel formulas you changed/added?

Comment: @JohnBustos thank you for the precious help wb.setForceFormulaRecalculation(true) didn't work for me but the link you gave was helpful; I didn't know that POI cached the previous calculated values so wb.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator().evaluateAll() fixed the problem.

Comment: @Gagravarr you were right, it was the cached values thing, I fixed it with wb.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator().evaluateAll(). Thank you, I appreciated your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the help of @JohnBustos and @Gagravarr, I fixed the problem using :
`wb.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator().evaluateAll();`

Apparently, Excel caches previously calculated results (in my case it was the Zero in the source Excel file) and we need to trigger **recalculation** to update them.

See this link : http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/eval.html / Section : "Recalculation of Formulas"

Comment: I was looking for this for a long time, thanks for sharing.