# Formula won't calculate before "Enable Editing"

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

There's one cell which has a formula and after generating the document, the value won't be calculated unless I click on "Enable Editing".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call worksheet.Calculate() before you save the document.

Comment: Good to hear ... Been caught out by that myself!! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49675963/why-wont-this-formula-calculate-unless-i-double-click-a-cell